# MySQL how to accumulate subtract between date in date list exclude Sunday

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

i have a list of date with data below:

```
3/23/2018
3/25/2018
3/29/2018
4/20/2018
4/22/2018
```

i want to subtract date (exclude Sunday) from up to down list to get number of day between 2 date in MySQL below:

```
Date List   Number of Day
3/23/2018   0               # first always = 0
3/25/2018   2               # 3/25/2018 - 3/23/2018
3/29/2018   3               # 3/28/2018 - 3/25/2019
4/20/2018   19              # 4/19/2018 - 3/29/2020
4/22/2018   2               # 4/22/2018 - 4/20/2021
```

any help would be appreciated. thanks.

Comment: is date column a varchar?

Comment: @RaymondNijland date column is DATE data type. and remarks is just formula description for easy to understand. the result i need is only Date List and Number of Day column.

Comment: Ok what MySQL version are you using?

Comment: @RaymondNijland MySQL version: 10.1.28-MariaDB